# Regex, matching backticks not nested within triple backticks

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match strings that are surrounded by backtick's but they aren't surrounded by triple backtick's.

For example:

match: `I should be matched`

should not match: ``` `Hello world` ```

This is what I've tried so far: https://regex101.com/r/P4MhiM/1

Comment: Very hard to do using regular expressions, especially if you start taking into account that there might be multiple triple-backtick blocks. You're better off writing a small parser.

Answer (score 0):

i get  pass this test case

first capture all match in single quote

```
\`(?:.+)\`
```

second filter the matchs only char not backticks nor white space

```
\`(?:[^\`||\s]+)\`
```

https://regex101.com/r/oVE7zi/1

Answer (score 0):

Match and capture a part of the match, then use custom logic in the replacement:

````js
const text = "\n``` `Hello world` ```\n\n\n`Matched!`\n";
const rx = /```.*?```|`([^`\n]+)`/g;
console.log(
  text.replace(rx, (x, y) => y ? `<code>${y}</code>` : x)
)
````

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P4MhiM/2). *Details*:

- ```` ```.*?``` ```` - strings between triple backticks (with no line breaks in between backticks)
- `|` - or
- `` `([^`\n]+)` `` - strings between backticks without line break chars.